# What is the difference between mach headers and fat headers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a static library supplied to me that I need to use in an app. I am told it supports ARM64.

When I list the mach headers using `otool -hV mylibrary.a`, then I only get `x86_64` for CPU type.

When I list the fat headers using `otool -fv mylibrary-a`, then I get CPU types I386, x86_64, ARM, ARMv7S. ARM64.

It was my understanding that I needed mach headers for the architectures that I am going to run on. However, the app works fine on 64 bit device.

What is the difference between fat headers and mach headers in iOS development ? Is this library safe to use for a 64-bit app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mach header and universal header provide similar information. They identify things like cputype and cpusubtype, amongst other things. The universal header also indicates the file offset/size for each architecture. I believe that universal header is obtaining information from the mach header, but I could easily be wrong about that.

If you are only seeing x86_64, try `otool -hv -arch all myLibrary.a`

FWIW, an easier way is to do `lipo -info myLibrary.a`. If you see the slice you need you should be good to go, provided the library itself is working properly for that slice.